# Oracle Apex: How i can make page item Display Only while can still be updated through Dynamic Action

Tags: oracle-apex

have a page with some page items (region on top of page) and an interactive grid below it. one of page item have sum of an ig column, another page item is Discount, after user enter any discount amount, there are more 2 columns updated/calculated with Dynamic Actions. how i can prevent user interaction with those page items except Discount which required to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom css class to that item and inline css for display only, or you can use custom attribute to item as disabled.
You can check afterwards on browser console on dom if it is on the correct level of the page item.

For example I have a textfield item on the page:[image]

if I use staticid or id that is generated by the Oracle Apex and on the page's execute when page load section:

```
$('#P30_ORDERNR').attr('disabled');
```

this will add disabled attribute to my item which means it can be set but not by user.

Comment: thanks @cengiz sevimli for your inputs, i have not that knowledge to use custom css class or inline css for display only, i searched there is a 'is-readonly' but didn't worked. will you please help?

Comment: I improved my comment, can you check @AhmedHaroon

Comment: hi @cengiz sevimli, on page load created a DA, true action Execute JavaScript Code copy/paste your code, replace P30_ORDERNR with my page item P32_AMOUNT ( # sign is there as you have used ), run the page and it still allow me to enter data. in my console i can see it has not set as ' disabled ' is there anything i missed?

Comment: now i used its Disable built in Action in dynamic action on page load and it works fine. thanks for your efforts to help me. kind regards

Comment: probably you should've inspect the DOM elements but yeah disabling the item also works.