Oracle APEX - display only item validation issue
I have a display only field on my page - P1_TEXT_DISPL that gets populated when another field on the page changes. If that field does not equal to "TEST_1" I need to display an error on the page. For that I used validation:
Type: Item=Value
Item: P1_TEXT_DISPL
Value: TEST_1

That wouldn't work and displayed the error message even when the item value was indeed "TEST_1".
I understands that this happens because the value of display only item is not saved into the session state, so I added a hidden field P1_TEXT_HIDE, set its value the same way I set the value of P1_TEXT_DISPL and added validation to the hidden field. I can see the value of P1_TEXT_HIDE in session but I still see error message displayed even when the value of hidden field is clearly stored in session as "TEST_1". Any other ways I can set up validation of display only field?

I think the problem is not the validation but how you set the value of the item P1_TEXT_DISPL. Normally, you wouldn't need another page item "P1_TEXT_HIDE". Can you provide more input about how do you set the "P1_TEXT_DISPL" value?

Validation works fine on display only item. Can you put together a minimal reproducible case on apex.oracle.com ?

@cengiz sevimli There is an LOV that the user selects a value from and based on the value selected several textboxes get populated.
One of the populated textboxes has a dynamic action that retrieves a value from database (based on the value of that textbox and dynamic action populates P1_TEXT_DISPL using Set Value action

Based on the scenario you provided, the problem is setting the value of the Display Only item. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121622/oracle-apex-how-i-can-make-page-item-display-only-while-can-still-be-updated-th/71122158#71122158

you were right. I changed the way I set the value and it fixed my problem. Please post the answer so I could accept it as a solution
